# Calling overloaded function with floating point literal yields 'ambiguos' error

Tags: c++, function, overloading

When compiling the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print(int i){
    cout << i << endl;
}

void print(float i){
    cout << i << endl;
}

int main(){
    print(5);
    print(5.5)
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error:

> call of overloaded 'print(double)' is ambiguous.

However, if I change

```
void print(float i){
```

to

```
void print(double i){
```

the code compiles. Why is that?

Comment: `5.5` is a `double` literal constant - change it to `5.5f` and it will work with `float`.

Comment: "call of overloaded 'print(double)' is ambiguous" mean that you did not use a float

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a different exercise to understand this. Removing either of the two overloads will make the program compile, although there's no identity match for the literal `5.5`, a double value, it can be implicitly converted to `int` or `float`.

When both overloads are present, since `5.5` can be implicitly converted to either a `int` or `float`, both are viable. The compiler is unable to decide between the two, hence the error.

Upon making the literal a `float`, `5.5f`, we've an identity match, the `float` overload and no ambiguity in decision for the compiler. Conversely, keeping the literal `double`, `5.5`, changing the function prototype from `float` to `double` also works since this is an identity match as well.

Comment: If 5.5 is not a float, what is a float than? I'm sorry i always used float with Python and in Python 5.5 is a float

Comment: @HugoCornel Python only has one floating-point type. C++ has two distinct types, `float` and `double`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `5.5` is of type `double`. Since `print` is overloaded, the compiler will look for the best match to find out which overload to call, a process called [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution). This is a quite complex set of rules, but here is what happens in your simple case:

First the compiler will check for an exact match, i.e. some `void print(double);` or the like.

Since this does not exist, it considers conversions. A `double` can be implicitly converted to both `int` and `float`, and those conversions are deemed equally good.

Thus, the compiler cannot decide which function overload it should call and complains that the call is ambiguous.

As already mentioned by others, you can fix this by
either getting the input type exactly right: `print(5.5f);`
 or adding an overload that is an unambiguously better match for a `double` argument, like e.g.

```
void print (double);
void print (const double&);
template <class T>
void print (T);
```

Answer (score 3):

Integer version:

```
void print(int i)
           ^^^ // This declaration wants an `int` type
```

Float version:

```
void print(float i)
           ^^^^^ // This declaration wants a `float` type
```

Usage:

```
print(5); // Calling print with `int`, finds the "Integer version"
print(5.5); // '5.5' is a `double` type, which is neither an `int` type nor a `float` type
```

Since a `double` type is specified and there is not a `double` overload a conversion to either `int` or `float` is required to use the existing overloads.

Using the existing overloads:

```
 print(5.5f); // Use a `float` literal (i.e., this is a `float` type)
 print(static_cast<float>(5.5)); // I'd recommend the former but this works
 print(static_cast<int>(5.5)); // Works but obviously truncates the value
```

Add a new overload (as opposed to updating the existing `float` overload):

```
void print(double i); // A new overload declaration
```

Comment: *"'5.5' is a `double` type which matches neither the "Integer version" nor the "Float version""*. Actually it matches both, but both are given a conversion rank (equally good from an overload resolution point of view)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yes, you're correct, poor wording on my part. I intended to convey that `double` is not a `float` or an `int` and each requires a single conversion. I'll try to make it more clear.